# Dropwizard good practices

Tags: json, database, resources, dropwizard

I have seen in a lot of places that a resource class in a dropwizard project has methods for GET and POST. These methods then access data from the database using the DAO and return back a json

```
public class DropwizardResource {

    private DropwizardDAO ddao;

    public DropwizardResource (DropwizardDAO ddao) {
        this.ddao = ddao;
    }

    @GET
    @Timed
    @UnitOfWork
    public List<String> getAllResources() {
        return ddao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Is it advisable to have a resource initialized with other clients for some other service and then have the json returned by manual conversion?

```
public class DropwizardResource {

    private NonDbClient client;

    public DropwizardResource (NonDbClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @GET
    @Timed
    @UnitOfWork
    public List<String> getAllResources() {
        return toJson(client.findAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you want to do? If you want to build a Rest to Soap adapter with dropwizard you have to init your ressource with a soap client. Thats ok. Then other REST client can access your service and you are doing a SOAP call for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's be clear: you can do whatever you like in a Dropwizard resource - there's nothing inherently special about them.

On your specific question on whether you can use "[a client] for some other service" (e.g. another Dropwizard service, or something completely separate), the answer is yes, that's perfectly fine. Note, however, if you're not using Hibernate to access a database within your resource method, you don't need the `@UnitOfWork` annotation (which is [for declaring that a session & transaction should be managed for you](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods) when that method is called).

Finally, you ask whether it's okay to "then have the json returned by manual conversion". It's a little hard to answer that question without knowing what client you're thinking of using, and what it returns when you call its `findAll` method. I can think of a couple of possible scenarios:

1. You get deserialised plain old Java objects back from your client (regardless of how they were serialised in transit - JSON, XML, crazy proprietary binary protocol, whatever). In this case, you just need to transform these into whatever object you want to return from your Dropwizard resource method (a `List<String>` in the case of your example). From there, Jersey and Jackson will deal with serialising this to JSON for you and putting that in the response from your resource.
2. You get a string containing JSON back from your client. In this case, you'll need to manually deserialise the JSON to Java objects (using a Jackson `ObjectMapper` - [you can grab one from the Dropwizard `Environment`](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.0/dropwizard-core/apidocs/io/dropwizard/setup/Environment.html#getObjectMapper--) in your application's `run` method). At that point you can transform then and return them as in the above case.

In either case, I can't think why you'd want to be serialising **to** JSON (as in your example). That'd give you a `String` (not a `List<String>`). Unless you're doing something pretty quirky, you probably don't want to be returning a JSON string from your Dropwizard resource - that will then serialise it as JSON again, and will then result in a string full of JSON being deserialised again at the other end!

Comment: Thank you, that was the explanation I was looking for!

Comment: Great, glad I could help clarify things a little!